# Keras ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_5 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (0,)

Tags: python, keras

I will really appreciate if someone can give me a hand... I been working on this for days and can get it to work...

here is the link if anyone wants to see the complete code.

https://github.com/TheStoneMX/APTOS-2019/blob/master/notebooks/keras-multi-model-input-image-cropping-Copy2.ipynb

```
def create_base_model(MODEL, img_size, lambda_fun = None):

    inp = Input(shape = (img_size[0], img_size[1], 3))
    x = inp
    if lambda_fun:
        x = Lambda(lambda_fun)(x)

    base_model = MODEL(input_tensor = x, weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False, pooling = 'avg')

    model = Model(inp, base_model.output)
    return model

model1 = create_base_model(vgg16.VGG16, (224, 224), vgg16.preprocess_input)
model2 = create_base_model(resnet50.ResNet50, (224, 224), resnet50.preprocess_input)
model3 = create_base_model(inception_v3.InceptionV3, (299, 299), inception_v3.preprocess_input)

model1.trainable = False
model2.trainable = False
model3.trainable = False

inpA = Input(shape = (224, 224, 3))
inpB = Input(shape = (299, 299, 3))

out1 = model1(inpA)
out2 = model2(inpA)
out3 = model3(inpB)

x = Concatenate()([out1, out2, out3]) 
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model([inpA, inpB], x)

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=2e-4)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs = 5,
    steps_per_epoch = train_num // batch_size,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = validation_num // batch_size,
    verbose = 1,
    callbacks = [mc, es])
```

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_5 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (0,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first suggestion, you might want to bypass all of the flow generation and data augmentation, and just see if you can train to a single input image.  You want to verify that your preprocessing is correct.  The warnings that occur right after the fit call are concerning, since they appear to indicate that the image data is not being loaded correctly, or not being found.  Something like this should work without error:

```
x_train_1 = np.random.uniform(size=(1,224,224,3))
x_train_2 = np.random.uniform(size=(1,299,299,3))
y_train = np.array([0])
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train,0)

print(x_train_1.shape)
print(x_train_2.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
model.fit(x=[x_train_1, x_train_2], y=y_train, epochs=1)
```

Then try loading real data (without augmentation), then finally convince yourself that the loading, flow/augmentation processing is correct.

Also, it might be useful to run the model.summary() command after the compile so you can see what the architecture is.  It might be useful to name the layers so that you can pinpoint which layer is in question.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, good idea I will try that and see, but how will you go about doing that? ([image1, image2], label) and one step per epoch? and will print the model summary.

Comment: @OscarRangel I modified my answer above to include a simple way to try this out.  To show model summary, just add the command "model.summary()" to your python code right after the model.compile.  I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! I will try it first as you have it, then I will create the numpy array with real image data read it from disk, and see, I will let you know, it may take a while as I am going out with family sunday. I guess this is the way to implement that,

Comment: thanks! I will try it first as you have it, then I will create the 
numpy array with real image data read it from disk, 
and see, I will let you know, I guess this is the way to implement that

Comment: x_train_1 = numpy.asarray(PIL.Image.open('test.jpg')) 
x_train_2 = numpy.asarray(PIL.Image.open('test2.jpg'))

x_train_1 = x_train_1.reshape((1,224,224,3))
 x_train_2 = x_train_1.reshape((1,224,224,3))

y_train = np.array([0])
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train,0

Comment: model.fit(x=[x_train_1, x_train_2], y=y_train, epochs=1)